# Which one is the correct option for this question?

Tags: functions

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x) = \dfrac{2x^2 - x + 5}{7x^2 + 2x + 10}$, then $f$ is: 
>  (a) one-one but not onto
>  (b) onto but not one-one 
>  (c) onto as well as one-one 
>  (d) neither onto nor one-one

I have tried this question by drawing the graph of the above function and also by applying limit I found that at infinity the above function is approaching 2/7 and also for this function to be onto Range=Co-Domain. But I can't understand that why this function is not onto? Because the answer is given option(d).

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting an image since users who rely on screen readers may not be able to read an image.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

If you drew the graph correctly, you'd see the graph looks like this:

[image]

Non-injectivity (i.e. not being one-to-one) is immediate, from the horizontal line test: for instance, at $x=-2$ the function is $15/34$, and you can then set the function equal to $15/34$ to find the other value $x$ that gives this, $10/37$.

Non-surjectivity (i.e. not being onto) is also somewhat immediate: we don't seem to see a value on the graph for which the function equals, say, $0$. And to see that, just set the function equal to zero:

$$\frac{2x^2 - x + 5}{7x^2 + 2x + 10} = 0 \implies \begin{cases}
2x^2 - x + 5 = 0 \\
\text{assuming } 7x^2 + 2x + 10 \ne 0 \end{cases}$$

The latter fact is trivial and holds for all real $x$, so I omit it. The former equation can be solved via the quadratic formula to have

$$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-39}}{4}$$

so obviously no real $x$ works. Hence, there is an element (namely, $0$) in the codomain which is not in the range, i.e. they're not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to proving that the function is not onto:

Given any 2nd degree polynomial of form $J(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$, it is well known that **if** $B^2 - 4AC < 0$, then it is impossible for there to exist any value $x$ such that $J(x)$ equals $(0)$.

For the stated function, let $g(x)$ represent the **numerator** of the function, and let $h(x)$ represent the **denominator** of the function.  Using the previous paragraph as a guideline, it is immediate that there is no value $(x)$ such that either $g(x) = 0$, or $h(x) = 0.$

From this, you can conclude that there is no value $x$ such that

$$\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = 0.$$

Therefore, the function can not possibly be **onto**, because the value $(0)$ is not in the range of the function.